# Norm of the Linear Operator

Tags: rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $G$ be a compact group, and $\pi : G \rightarrow \mathcal{U}(H)$ be a continuous unitary representation. Let $f \in L^{1}(G)$ be arbitrary.

By Riesz Representation Theorem we can find a bounded linear map $T: H \rightarrow H$ such that

$\langle T \xi, \eta \rangle = \int_{G} f(x)\langle \pi(x)\xi, \eta \rangle dx$,

Let $\tilde{\pi}(f) : = T$.

What is the norm of $\tilde{\pi}$?

Comment: As with most questions of the "what is" kind, the natural counter-question is: In what terms do you want the answer to be stated? Do you have reasons to believe that there is an answer stated in non-tautological terms?

Comment: There is no formula for the norm unless more information is given about the function $f$ and the representation $\pi$. I am voting to close as "question not well-defined"